# How to hash my password in Go, for storing in the mongodb database?

Tags: go, hash, bcrypt

Here is my `/models` folder which contains the schema. How hould I hash the password for storing in the mongodb database?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgPTg.png)

I used the bcrypt package from Go, but was unable to achieve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword` to get the hashed password:

```
package password

import "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

func Hash(password string) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)
    return string(bytes), err
}

func Verify(hashed, password string) bool {
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hashed), []byte(password))
    return err == nil
}
```